# Bigquery PARSE_TIMESTAMP of format 2018-10-03T23:00:42.690Z

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery

My Bigquery table contains timestamp as string and to use bigquery TIMESTAMP functions I need to parse it.
However, I am unable to parse the string. `My timestamp value looks like as 2018-10-03T23:00:42.690Z`

Kindly suggest how to parse this in bigquery. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it:

```
SELECT CAST('2018-10-03T23:00:42.690Z' AS TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see that the casting does not work on the format 2018-05-29T10:55:01.40+10:00 which is my localTimestamp. Can you please suggest this as well. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "does not work". Casting that string to a TIMESTAMP succeeds for me as well.

Comment: When using casting on the format 2018-05-29T10:55:01.40+10:00. I get the error as: Invalid time zone: +1000

Comment: `SELECT CAST('2018-05-29T10:55:01.40+10:00' AS TIMESTAMP)` succeeds for me. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Thanks Elliott. It seems like my data has some issue.